# Which job properties get merged vs overwritten when using `extends` in GitLab CI?

Tags: inheritance, gitlab, gitlab-ci, extends, gitlab-ci.yml

In GitLab CI, you can use the [extends](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends) keyword in order to inherit properties from another job or template.

One example is:

```
.tests:
  script: rake test
  stage: test
  only:
    refs:
      - branches

rspec:
  extends: .tests
  script: rake rspec
  only:
    variables:
      - $RSPEC
```

Which results in:

```
rspec:
  script: rake rspec
  stage: test
  only:
    refs:
      - branches
    variables:
      - $RSPEC
```

But as you can see, it is not obvious how each property gets merged. Properties like "only" appear to get merged and other properties like `script` appear to get overwritten instead.

I'm trying to understand exactly which properties get overwritten and which properties get merged (and how). Is there a complete list?

Something like this maybe?

| Property | Behavior when used with `extends` |
| --- | --- |
| `script` | Overwritten |
| `only` | Merged |
| `except` | Merged |
| `variables` | Merged |
| `before_script` | Overwritten |
| `after_script` | Overwritten |
| `needs` | Merged |
| `cache` | Merged (gets converted from map to list of maps) |
| `artifacts` | Merged (deep) |
| `services` | ? |
| `when` | ? |
| `rules` | ? |
| ... | ... |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in [merge details](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#merge-details), hashes (key, value pairs) get merged, but any other value like arrays are overwritten by the extending job. It works simply by using the [deep_merge](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_merge) method which is part of the Ruby on Rails framework.

The actual logic, looks like this:

```rb
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb, line 23
  def deep_merge!(other_hash, &block)
    merge!(other_hash) do |key, this_val, other_val|
      if this_val.is_a?(Hash) && other_val.is_a?(Hash)
        this_val.deep_merge(other_val, &block)
      elsif block_given?
        block.call(key, this_val, other_val)
      else
        other_val
      end
    end
  end
```

This means it can be important how you write your YAML, as some configurations accept multiple types. For example `variables:` may be a hash of keys and values (or hash of keys and hash of configuration options). It can also be an array of hashes. These different options for writing `variables:` will merge differently when used with `extends:`. The same goes for many other keys, like `only:` and `except:`.